# Using Form button/Eloquent to set an entire column to null

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am having a real issue getting a button to scan and clear out an entire column using an eloquent model. I have two columns in my SQLite DB, "States" and "Totals"... I want the States to stay in their own order, but I want the totals to be cleared out upon the user selecting a button. The character type for 'totals' is BigInt... After the user selects the button, I want them redirected to the home page (with the values cleared so they can start over).

Here are my routes:

```
Route::resource('states', 'StateController');
Route::get('/', 'StateController@index');
Route::post('create', 'StateController@store');
Route::post('states.update', 'StateController@update');
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function update()
{
    Distributors::update(['total' => null]);
    return View::make('states');
}
```

Here is my form:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'states.update']) }}

{{ Form::submit('Destroy and Start Anew') }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

The error I get is:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Is there a simple issue with my routes? I can't figure it out.

Comment: does your error show `at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST'))`  it is around the second line in the error details ? most likely your form is posted to a get route instead of post route.

Comment: Frankly I gave up on it and turned it into a link. Now I get an error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such column: totals (SQL: update "distributors" set "totals" = 0, "updated_at" = 2015-08-21 03:44:19 where "totals" != 0)

Comment: Distributors::where('totals', '!=', '0')->update(['totals' => 0]);

Comment: your column name is `total` or `totals` in you table?

Comment: Also can you past your html markup, please?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a `method` attribute on your form, so it will automatically execute a GET request. Your `state.update` route is only setup to accept POST requests.

Change your form to this:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'states.update', 'method' => 'post']) }}
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier, but it didnt work. I used the <a href="clear" method="POST">Clear the data and create a new map</a> and it worked. I believe that it may have been a mistake in typography, but I also seeded the entire database with timestamps this time. Before I was using "State" as the primary key and had no timestamps in the DB. I also was using bigInt when i shoulda used 'integer' while migrating the DB. I am not sure what fixed it, but it is working now and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete

> Route::resource('states', 'StateController');

in your route and try again.